# Free up space on dropbox cloud by "ignoring" local files and directories (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: sync, dropbox

I have some big files in directories that need to be shared on dropbox but these big files themselves should not be uploaded to dropbox (because they are filling my quota way to fast).

It seems that there is now the possibility to "ignore" such files or directories, see https://superuser.com/a/1527145/728074. (Note that dropbox calls preventing from syncing cloud to local "excluding" and local to cloud "ignoring". See https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/restore-delete/ignored-files and https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/linux-commands).

I used `attr -s com.dropbox.ignored -V 1 /path/to/somewhere` to exclude many big files but I did not get back any space on dropbox. Is there a way to get back the space? Should I delete them from the cloud (through the browser). Will it leave my local copies alone since they now have the "ignored" tag?

---

It seems it might immediately remove the corresponding files from the cloud and give you back the space only it takes a while. Will update if I got all my space back for files that I "ignored".

Answer (score 0):

After running the command `attr -s com.dropbox.ignored -V 1 /path/to/somewhere` the files are automatically deleted from the cloud and you get back the space automatically. However, this can take some time (a few minutes) to take effect.